# Fetching with parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-teams

As a quick summary, im trying to fetch from a URL and do so with 2 parameters.
I have no experience with javascript so i was trying this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    $input = array("team" => {teamName}, "name" => {userPrincipalName});
    fetch("http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input=".urlencode(json_encode($input)))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            files: result.files
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
}
```

This however does not seem to work. So my question would be: how do i succesfully pass the teamName and userPrincipalName from the context to the json_encode.

There is however 1 more problem with my code. I currently have two componentDidMounts, which are both using setState. The problem seems to be that whatever setState happens last, is the one that is being worked with, while the first setState is being completely overwritten. But i do need to do both the context setState AND the fetch to achieve my goal.

Here is my full code to give as clear an image as possible of what im doing:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      context: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    microsoftTeams.getContext((context, error) => {
      this.setState({
        context: context
      });
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $input = array("team" => {teamName}, "name" => {userPrincipalName});
    fetch("http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input=".urlencode(json_encode($input)))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            files: result.files
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
  
  render() {  
    const { teamName, userPrincipalName } = this.state.context; 
    const { error, isLoaded, files } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (     
        <ul>
          {files.map(file => (
            <li key={file.id}>
              {file.name} {file.type}
              <span id="user">Team: {teamName}, userPrincipalName: {userPrincipalName }</span>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>       
      );
    }
    
  }

}
export default Tab;
```

TL;DR
How do i use setState two times without problems? and how do i work the parameters teamName and userPrincipalName into my fetch?

Thank you!

Comment: Give me an example of how the final URL should look llke, being teamName = "TeamA" and userPrincipalName = "Joe".

Comment: @MarksASP for now lets start with just the userPrincipalName, im a slow learner...
So in this case the URL would be: `http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input="John"`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you need is backticks:

```
`http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input=${userPrincipalName}`
```

Comment: This did not fix the problem as ${userPrincipalName} is undefined. The right solution seems to be: `'http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input='+'"'+ {userPrincipalName}+'"'` But for some reason  my {userPrincipalName} is not actually containing the username but rather [object Object]

Comment: It's `object Object` because you're wrapping the variable inside `{}`. That turns it into this object: `{ userPrincipalName: "whatever value it has" }`. If you want to concatenate with `+` operator, remove the brackets. If you want to concatenate with backticks, do `${userPrincipalName}` (dolar sign at the start).

Comment: If `userPrincipalName` might be `undefined` then do `http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input=${userPrincipalName || ""}`. That will replace the value of `userPrincipalName` in case it's falsy (undefined, null, false, "") with an empty string

Comment: im currently using `const queryParameters = new URLSearchParams({ function: 'getDocuments', input: userPrincipalName});` So it is no longer [object Object] but instead its now Undefined. I seems to me that there is something wrong with grabbing the userPrincipalName from the context. It looks like no value is being put into userPrincipalName right now. Maybe this has something to do with me having two componentDidMount()? Or the setState is being updated too quick?

Comment: you're right if i use `http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input=${userPrincipalName || ""}` it returns an empty string. So now im even more confused as to how to get the userPrincipalName to display properly in my URL fetch...